# View need restarting the tkinter app

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have made tkinter app along with sqlite3 with many frames in it. I have made several tables. I can add items to the table without any flaws. However, I need to close and reopen the app to view the added changes in the database. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Please give us an example. However the solution may be either use tkinter `update()` or use multithreading to avoid window frozing.

Comment: If you use a function to place everything inside of a frame then you can simple `destroy()` the frame and then rerun that function to pull everything again. Should be simple enough. Can you provide an example code of what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solution is to write your code in such a way that you can reload the data. There's no special trick to doing that, but it doesn't happen for free. All widgets have a method for modifying their data. You simply need to detect when a change occurs (or give the user a "refresh" button), and then reload the data.